# How to get rid of those two tranparent stripes above and below Google Maps?

Tags: joomla-3.x, css, fix-my-code

I'm trying to customize my Joomla 3 template and I'm kinda stuck with an issue I don't know exactly how to resolve. There're two margins just above and just below Google Maps on homepage. And what happens is that video background is visible in those stripes.
I was told that I had the

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

inside of a

```
 <p></p>
```

to remove those

```
 <p></p>
```

because they have a margin. Meaning not to touch the div itself and also not to delete what's within those tags, just to delete the tags. It's all nice, but I don't have a clue where to find it, in which specific file. Here's the live site URL:

idevsky.com

Also I'm attaching a print screen in which I drew two red arrows to show exactly what I meant.

[image]

Comment: This question is solved. Had to edit Google Maps code. That's all.

Comment: Would it be possible to explain how you solved it? That will help others with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

In Joomla's Custom HTML module where original Google Maps code was, I had to change the old code:

```
 <p><iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1-bVo4tCI2bNdO1Ssj9CySDIWIJ0" width="1360" height="480"></iframe></p>
```

To this new one:

```
  <p style="margin:0;"><iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1-bVo4tCI2bNdO1Ssj9CySDIWIJ0" width="1360" height="480"></iframe></p>
```